# change the template of an item after clicking on it

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have a class named :

```
public class CountryTemplateSelector : ContentControl
    {
        public DataTemplate TrueTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
            }

        public DataTemplate FalseTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }



        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
           Shopping_Ingredients itemAux = item as Shopping_Ingredients;
            if (itemAux != null)
            {
                if (itemAux.IsMarked == true)
                    return TrueTemplate;
                else 
                    return FalseTemplate;
            }

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
 public virtual DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return null;
        }

        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

            ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, this);
        }
    }
```

and a DataTemplate declared in App.xaml :

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectorForCheckbox">
            <local:CountryTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                <local:CountryTemplateSelector.TrueTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="82">
                            <CheckBox  Name="cb1" FontSize="15" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMarked, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="0,4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.485,0.365" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AmountToString}" Margin="15,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CountryTemplateSelector.TrueTemplate>
                <local:CountryTemplateSelector.FalseTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="82">
                            <CheckBox  Name="cb1" FontSize="15" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMarked, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="0,4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.485,0.365" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="TEST" Margin="15,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </local:CountryTemplateSelector.FalseTemplate>
             </local:CountryTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and a LongListSelector :

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="recipe1" Background="Transparent" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectorForCheckbox}"
                    ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource citiesListHeader}"
                        ListFooterTemplate="{StaticResource citiesListFooter}"
                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}"
                    GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource groupItemTemplate}" >
                    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
                </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

The LongListSelector launches ok, and the templates are shown ok. The problem is that i would like to be able to change the template of the specific item clicked. How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to set the templates in code. See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991726/set-silverlight-template-from-code). Make sure that all the templates needed are resources in the App.xaml or in your specific UserControl. My example is from a button click, but the same approach should apply elsewhere in code. I'm not 100% certain it should be cast to ControlTemplate. It will probably very per template.

```
public void CLick_Method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 this.recipe1.ItemTemplate = (ControlTemplate)Resources["SelectorForX"];
 this.recipe1.ListHeaderTemplate= (ControlTemplate)Resources["NewListHeaderTemplate"];
// etc.
}
```

Comment: tnx for the response! the thing is that i would like to change ONLY the template for the specific item clicked! (for example i would like to have a green background once the item is clicked). The other items should have the initial template assign